# Python library to draw lines in 3d space

Tags: python, blender

I'm working on a project where I'll need to create a video of a line in 3d space moving about. I'm wondering, what would the best Python library be for this?

My worst-case scenario is using MatPlotLib and making a video from the pictures, but that would be pretty terrible.

I've also heard Blender is good for 3d animation, but it seems really complicated to just draw a simple line. Still, that could be the way to go.

I'm a good Python programmer, but haven't done visual stuff in it ever.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe what you are looking for is something like `Glue` library. [Here](http://glueviz.org/) you can find the link to it.
Hope it's helpful.